# aws lambda 250MB以上の外部パッケージライブラリの読み込み方法

Tags: python, ubuntu, aws-lambda

AWS lambda関数をgreengrass coreをインストールしたjetsonにデプロイして、
そのデプロイ先のjetsonに置いてある外部パッケージをLambda関数で使用したいと考えています。

しかし、jetsonに置いてある外部パッケージをimportしようとすると、
greengrassのログにはエラーも何も出力されずLambdaが落ちてしまいます。

外部パッケージはpytorchなどを含んでおり、サイズが700MBになるため
250MB制限に引っかかりLambda関数に一緒にアップロードすることもできません。

試したこととしては、
外部パッケージを置いてあるディレクトリのパーミッションを777に変更。
Lambdaを通さずにjetsonのローカルで関数を動かしてみると問題なく動く。
importの順番を変更しても外部パッケージのライブラリはすべて同じ現象が起こる。

この問題の解決策を教えてください。
ライブラリを読み込みさえすればいいので、別の回避策でもかまいません。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numpyのバージョンが原因でライブラリが読み込めなかったことが判明しました。
どうやらnumpyが1.19.5以上だとエラーになるようです。
numpyのバージョンを下げることで解決いたしました。

Answer (score 0):

[Lambda with Container Image](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/news/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/) は使えませんでしょうか？
他に EFS を使う方法もあるようですが。